# How to remove preprint submitted to Elsevier in cas_dc class template

Tags: elsarticle, els-cas

I have used cas_dc class as a template. I tried to remove the footer 'preprint submitted to Elsevier using this code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@first{%
   \let\@oddhead\@empty
   \let\@evenhead\@empty
   \def\@oddfoot{}
   \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
```

it removes the footer from the first page only.
I tried this code as well:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@cas{%
   \let\@oddhead\@empty
   \let\@evenhead\@empty
   \def\@oddfoot{}
   \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
```

but nothing changed

Could you please help me on how to remove the footer
Thank you

Comment: Slightly unorthodox, but you can do `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_gset:Npn \__first_footerline: { \group_begin: \small \sffamily \__short_authors: \group_end: } \ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: With the document class defining the footer using LaTeX 3 definitions (within [`cas-common.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/cas-common.sty)), that's the way to go in my opinion. Write it up!

Comment: The class is intended for submissions to Elsevier. Use it only for this purpose: the code is quite badly written, unfortunately.

Comment: @Werner Done (and hopefully made it clear enough that it shouldn't be used :)

Answer (score 7):

**Please don't.**

As you were advised in the comments, this class is intended for submissions to Elsevier and should probably not be used otherwise, and if you're submitting to Elsevier there is no reason to change the layout in any way.

But supposing you have a real good reason for doing this, you can add

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \__first_footerline:
  { \group_begin: \small \sffamily \__short_authors: \group_end: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

to your preamble and it should do what you want (code crossed out for added drama :).

The convention with `expl3` is to *not* redefine or use macros with `__<package>` in their name because those macros are internal to `<package>`.  The els-cas templates however don't use a module consistently (the code above has `__first` and `__short`, which are definitely *not* the `<package>` here), so if you really need to remove that sentence from the footer, bite the bullet and use that code, but beware it may stop working<sup>1</sup> without notice.

  Because the template otherwise works so flawlessly.

Comment: I believe a good reason is when one will be submitting it to the journal but need to get the internal review first which if they see the footer indicated that it has been already submitted, it will raise questions. Likewise, it may be that the manuscript is part of a conference where you are getting final feedback before submitting it and already have the manuscript in the format ready for submitting it to the journal.

Answer (score 0):

just comment the lines in elsearticle.cls. I tried and this worked for synthetic metals

Comment: "elsarticle.cls" is licensed under the LPPL. If you suggest making changes to the class file, you should also suggest to rename it.